# I may have been trying to reach her. (is this tense a past progressive or present perfect progressive?)

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, progressive-aspect, auxiliary

> I may have been trying to reach her.

As the question in the title, I wonder if this sentence means

a past progressive or a present perfect progressive.

And what if the 'may' is changed to 'might'?

Comment: Hi. This is an odd thing to say because it would imply that you have forgotten or are unsure what you did. Is that what you mean?  If you mean that you tried to reach her, but were unsuccessful then say "I couldn't reach her", or "I tried to reach her, but couldn't", or if you need that specific tense "I had been trying to reach her, but couldn't".

Comment: It only makes sense if it's an unconscious effort where you don't realize what you're actually doing. In this case, if you unconsciously want to make contact with someone you may unconsciously do something to attract their attention. But knowing the source would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means:

> It's possible that I was trying to reach her.

Only you can say why the speaker doesn't know whether they were trying or not!

The distinction between *may* and *might* has become rather blurred; a lot of people use them interchangeably. I regard *might* as referring to a possibility in the past, so *I might have been trying to reach her* would mean 'It was possible (at the time) that I was trying to reach her'.

Answer (score 0):

The form "may have been trying" in the sentence from your question is the [**present perfect progressive**](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/present_perfect_progressive_tense.htm) (which can also be called the *present perfect continuous*).  Note that it is also in the **subjunctive** mood due to the presence of the auxiliary "may."

The present perfect is sometimes just called the 'perfect': it isn't always necessary to specify 'present' unless you're specifically differentiating it from (for example) the *past perfect*.

The *past progressive* of "try" is "was/were trying."  The *(present) perfect progressive* is "have been trying," and the *past perfect progressive* is "had been trying."

**"I may have been trying"** is fully specified by the term "1st person singular, (present) perfect progressive active subjunctive."